# Android Navigation from various Activities

Tags: user-interface, android-activity, navigation

According to image, I want following navigation from one Activity to another,

Home Screen (Menu 4) -> Activity 4 -> Activity 5 -> Activity 6 -> Activity  2

But I have to follow below two Constraints,

1. Back press on Activity 2 will redirect to Home Screen rather than Activity 6.
2. And User can able to go Activity 6 -> Activity 5 on back press and same for Activity 5 -> Activity 4. (So **NoHistory** attribute will not work for Activity 4, 5, 6, right?)

[image]

Please give suggestion to implement above Scenario. 
Thanks!

Comment: hi i am not clear .you mean from activity 6 you need to go to home screen directely when the user press back button.

Comment: @ManiTeja Hi, when user goes from Activity 6 to Activity 2. And on back press button on Activity 2, User should redirect to Home Screen instead of Activity 6.

Comment: hi there is no link from activity 6 to acticity 2 both are seperate right

Comment: No There is link from Activity 6 to Activity 2. I forgot to draw.

Answer (score 0):

hi from activity 2 call this way

```
Intent i = new intent(Activity2.this,Activity4.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

> in activity 4:

```
 Intent i = new intent(Activity4.this,Activity5.class);
     startActivity(i);  
finish();
```

> ```
> in activity 5:
> ```

```
  Intent i = new intent(Activity5.this,Activity6.class);
         startActivity(i);  
    finish();
```

know it will be in activity6 when you press back it will go to activity2 and and from there to main screen when u press back

Comment: let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Thanks! 
But in this implementation if user can't go back from Activity 5 to Activity 4.

Comment: boss the your main question will fail .or use fragments insted of activity

Comment: Have you understood question completely?

Comment: boss carry on i will do one sample by today and let you know clearly .

Comment: Please don't bother. I have found way. Btw Thanks a lot! When user will press back button then I will start Activity(HomeScreen) with CLEAR_TOP flag.

Comment: When user will press back button then I will start Activity(HomeScreen) with CLEAR_TOP flag. So It will open Home Screen from Activity Stack.